# Nest search query returning different results from the Elastic query DSL

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have an ElasticSearch index called `challenges`, which contains objects of type `Challenge`.

When I execute the following filter query in the Kibana console, it returns the 9 results, which are correct.

```
GET challenges/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "type": "Orphan"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

However, the following query from the Nest client, returns zero hits:

```cs
var challenges = await _client.SearchAsync<Challenge>(s => s
  .Query(q => +q
    .Term(t => t.Type, Models.Enums.ChallengeType.Orphan)
  )
);
```

I've also tried the following variation, to no avail:

```cs
var challenges = await _client.SearchAsync<Challenge>(s => s
  .Query(q => q
    .Bool(b => b
      .Filter(f => f
        .Term(t => t
          .Field(f => f.Type)
          .Value(challengeType)
        )
      )
    )
  )
);
```

The type property on which I'm filtering, is an enum with the following values:

```cs
public enum ChallengeType
{
  SixDimensions,
  Intro,
  Normal,
  UserCreated,
  Orphan,
  Youmate
}
```

and is stored as a keyword in the index.
An example object that is actually in the index:

```json
{
  "id": "3bce0ce1-9676-4858-b165-1442a443bf5a",
  "icon": "water-bottle.png",
  "index": 0,
  "default-time": "09:00",
  "default-days": [
    "Saturday",
    "Monday",
    "Wednesday"
  ],
  "default-repetitions": 3,
  "category": "A",
  "title": {
    "Persian": "آب خوردن"
  },
  "dimension": "Physical",
  "type": "Orphan",
  "id-package": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "intro-pages": [ ],
  "date-created": "2020-10-14T12:39:21.8427517+03:30",
  "notify": true,
  "template": 0,
  "belongs-to-user": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "active": false
}
```

Do you have any suggestions as to why the results from the console differ from when it is executed from the Nest client?

Comment: What is the query that the `NEST` client generated? Did you take a look at it?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. If it is supposed to be in the response object in the ApiCall -> Uri -> Query, then it is only this: "?typed_keys=true" and there is no indication of the actual filter query.

Comment: The search response that you receive has a property called `DebugInformation`. You can check that to see the query that is being generated by the `NEST` client.

Comment: Here it is:

Valid NEST response built from a successful (200) low level call on POST: /challenges/_search?typed_keys=true
# Audit trail of this API call:
 - [1] HealthyResponse: Node: http://localhost:9200/ Took: 00:00:00.4857527
# Request:
<Request stream not captured or already read to completion by serializer. Set DisableDirectStreaming() on ConnectionSettings to force it to be set on the response.>
# Response:
<Response stream not captured or already read to completion by serializer. Set DisableDirectStreaming() on ConnectionSettings to force it to be set on the response.>

Comment: @SaiGummaluri Thank you. I've disabled direct streaming on connection settings and it showed the actual request. Looking at the information I found out the problem was that I had indexed the property as its string equivalent, but the query was requesting its enum-integer value. Thus the problem. It solved when I called .ToString() on the enum.

Comment: Alright! Glad you could figure it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

The enum should be marked with `StringEnumAttribute` to serialize as a string

```cs
[StringEnum]
public enum ChallengeType
{
    SixDimensions,
    Intro,
    Normal,
    UserCreated,
    Orphan,
    Youmate
}
```

Without this, the enum will be serialized as its underlying integer value.